# JavaScript .length performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have a pretty mundane task, but I got to wondering how the performance of these two methods vary. I'm trying to get the total number of checked checkboxes and display that to the user:

```
$(document).on('change', ':checkbox', function() {
    if ( $(this).is(':checked') )
        count++;
    else
        count--;

    $count.html(count);
 });
```

versus

```
 $(document).on('change', ':checkbox', function() {
    $count.html($(':checkbox:checked').length);
 });
```

Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, `length` isn't a jQuery property. It's a plain [JavaScript array property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length).

Comment: Second one should be faster, since it has less actions to perform, right?

Comment: Both will be so fast that you don't ever need to care.

Comment: @MattAltepeter - the `.length` in the second code segment above is a jQuery object property that is maintained by the jQuery object.  it is NOT an array property.  A jQuery object contains an array, but it is not an array by itself.  So, this `.length` is a jQuery specific property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with all performance questions, if you really, really thought the performance difference might be relevant in your application (which seems unlikely since it's just responding to a user event), then you would have to measure, measure, measure to see which was actually faster.

In general, running a few extra lines of Javascript code is way faster than searching the entire DOM to find things so a guess based on that logic would be that `$(':checkbox:checked')` would be slower than `if ( $(this).is(':checked') )`.  But `.is()` isn't a particularly fast operation either.

So, here's a test case built in jsperf: http://jsperf.com/checkbox-count that I put a fair amount of HTML into the test page.  Your mileage might vary if you had a smaller DOM to search.

The `if ($(this).is(':checked'))` option is more than 500 times faster in all modern browsers.  Here's the graphic comparison.  The `$(':checkbox:checked').length` is so much slower that the blue bar does not even show in the graph.

[image]

Here are the actual numbers for **"Operations per Second"** in each browser:

Chrome `.is(...)`:  934,632
Chrome `$(...).length`: 498

IE 11 `.is(...)`: 209,333
IE 11 `$(...).length` 268

Firefox `.is(...)`:  1,227,712
Firefox `$(...).length`: 251

As you can see, this is a pretty stunning difference.  DOM searching is slow.  But, it probably still wouldn't make any actual difference in the code example you showed because this is just a few milliseconds difference in response to a user event.  The slowest operation up there is still less than **5ms** so that is probably not something that could be noticed in a simple event handler.

But, if this was part of something that was being evaluated in a loop over and over as part of a longer calculation, then it could make a big difference in a case like that.

Comment: Wow, awesome. Thanks so much for this! Yeah, I didn't figure it would make a big difference in my use case.

Answer (score 1):

> how the performance of these two methods vary

It won't. The performance gain of using one versus the other is negligible, there's no way it would be noticed and there are many things that you should optimize instead of doing those micro-optimizations.

I would advise going for the more readable `length`, it's only one line of code and it's easy to read and understand. You won't gain or lose any performance in execution time, but you might gain some performance from your coworkers if your code is easier to read and understand. ;)

Comment: If you actually measure, the performance difference is not negligible.  It may not be noticed in this circumstance, but the difference is not negligible.

Comment: That's a fair point. Still, from what I see in your benchmarks, it's a difference of a few miliseconds. I guess my point was that there are more important things to focus on, unless you're doing a looot of these operations in loops or something.

Comment: If there were thousands of checkboxes, there might be. :)

Answer (score 0):

For jQuery `.on`, `.live` or `.delegate methods`, check changes in `$(myMainElement)` and find the element expected for you.

```
$(myElementChanged).on('change', Find, function{})
```

`$(document)` is all your DOM and the jQuery checks all elements for `Find` every time.

Change this to `div` or the element if receiving the `Find`.

Example:

```
$(document).on
```

to

```
$('div#myForm').on
```

and restrict the area for checking.